# Why do we pass request as a parameter in the render method of django?

Tags: python, django, request

I have noticed that when using the `render()` function, we pass `request` as the first parameter, what's the use of this?

Also, can somebody explain using an example, when would it be necessary to use `render()` function instead of `render_to_response()` function for rending templates?

Answer (score 0):

You can checks the docs [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). Examples are there as well.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/
this link explained a bit more, from what I understand, it is essential to pass request as a parameter because Django need at least to know where the path is to render that template, and this information is stored in request.path

A more formal explain [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render):

> If **request** is provided, it must be an HttpRequest. Then the engine
>   must make it, as well as the CSRF token, available in the template.
>   How this is achieved is up to each backend.